# Changing text color with JavaScript Object Constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, object

I'm a noob here and appreciate some advice on this problem I'm trying to figure out. I realize there's probably better ways to do this without using an object constructor but I'm working on getting a better understanding of objects. My question is if there is something like this.function that references all the other objects that didn't call my function. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    
    a:visited {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="one"> Test</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="two"> Test again</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#" id="three">Tester </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="four"> Testify</a> </li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    var first = document.getElementById('one');
    var second = document.getElementById('two');
    var third = document.getElementById('three');
    var fourth = document.getElementById('four');

    var colorChange = function(theID) {
      this.id = theID;
      this.formatContent = () => {
        this.id.style.color = "red";
      };
    }

    test = new colorChange(first);
    testAgain = new colorChange(second);
    tester = new colorChange(third);
    testify = new colorChange(fourth);

    function createEventListeners() {
      if (first.addEventListener) {
        first.addEventListener("click", test.formatContent, false);
      }
      if (second.addEventListener) {
        second.addEventListener("click", testAgain.formatContent, false);
      }
      if (third.addEventListener) {
        third.addEventListener("click", tester.formatContent, false);
      }
      if (fourth.addEventListener) {
        fourth.addEventListener("click", testify.formatContent, false);
      }
    }

    function init() {
      createEventListeners();
    }

    if (window.addEventListener) {
      //call init() on page load
      console.log("> Adding TC39 Event Listener...");
      window.addEventListener("load", init, false);
    } else if (window.attachEvent) {
      console.log("> Adding MS Event Listener...");
      window.attachEvent("onload", init);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You'll notice that when you click one of the li items it will change its color to red. The problem is that this doesn't clear when you click another li. My thought was that I could just tell the browser to change all other objects to black when formatContent() is ran. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here's a pen if needed: https://codepen.io/seanbarker182/pen/JexPVz

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You haven't added any code to clear it.

Comment: Yeah I realize there isn't anything in there to change the color back so I shouldn't expect it to clear in its current state. I was hoping to get some advice on the best way to clear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this to learn about objects, using `prototype` is one way to get what you want:

```js
var colorChange = function (theID) {
  this.id = theID;
  this.instances.push(this);
  this.formatContent = () => {
  this.revertColors();
  this.id.style.color = "red"
  };
}

colorChange.prototype.instances = [];
colorChange.prototype.revertColors = function() {
  this.instances.forEach(instance => (instance.id.style.color = "black"))
}
```

This code stores instances on the `prototype` object that is shared by all the class instances when you initialize it. You can reach to this array from any instance and do modifications that you require.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('one');
var second = document.getElementById('two');
var third = document.getElementById('three');
var fourth = document.getElementById('four');

var colorChange = function (theID) {
 this.id = theID;
  this.instances.push(this);
  this.formatContent = () => {
  this.revertColors();
  this.id.style.color = "red"
  };
}

colorChange.prototype.instances = [];
colorChange.prototype.revertColors = function() {
  this.instances.forEach(instance => (instance.id.style.color = "black"))
}

test = new colorChange(first);
testAgain = new colorChange(second);
tester = new colorChange(third);
testify = new colorChange(fourth);

function createEventListeners() {
   if (first.addEventListener) {
    first.addEventListener("click", test.formatContent, false);
  } if (second.addEventListener) {
    second.addEventListener("click", testAgain.formatContent, false);
  } if (third.addEventListener) {
    third.addEventListener("click", tester.formatContent, false);
  } if (fourth.addEventListener) {
    fourth.addEventListener("click", testify.formatContent, false);
  }
}

function init(){
 createEventListeners();
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
  //call init() on page load
   console.log("> Adding TC39 Event Listener...");
   window.addEventListener ("load", init, false);
}
else if (window.attachEvent) {
   console.log("> Adding MS Event Listener...");
   window.attachEvent ("onload", init);
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#0" id="one"> Test</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#0" id="two"> Test again</a> </li>
 <li><a href="#0" id="three">Tester </a></li>
 <li><a href="#0" id="four"> Testify</a> </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Took me forever to figure out why this worked in the example but not on my real project. Spent over an hour debugging and kept getting a type error on 'this.instances.push(this);'. Turned out that I called the colorChange object in my init function. Works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your `formatContent` method:

```
this.formatContent = () => {
    if (this.id.style.color == "black") {
        this.id.style.color = "red";
    } else {
        this.id.style.color = "black";
    }
};
```

## EDIT:

To make only the clicked one red, first make an array:

```
var elements = [first, second, third, fourth];
```

Then loop over it in the function and set them all to black:

```
this.formatContent = () => {
    elements.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.style.color = "black";
    }
    this.id.style.color = "red";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! When I add that it no longer changes any of the text colors. Edit: Actually I made some changes and it does change the color to red and if I click it again it changes back to black. What I want it to do is change to red if I click 'Test' but then if I click 'Test Again' I want that to turn red and 'Test' to turn black

Comment: Yeah that's what I changed to get that working but I might have been unclear in what I'm looking to accomplish. I edited my comment above to clarify. Basically I want it to act like :active in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There's a slightly easier way to achieve this where you don't need ids, and you only need to set one event listener.

Here's a stripped-down example:

```js
// Grab the main ul element and attach a click
// listener to it. This will listen to events that
// bubble up the DOM from other clicked elements
// (event propagation)
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
ul.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// Grab the list items
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');

function handleClick(e) {

  // Grab the classList property from the event target
  const { classList } = e.target;

  // Loop over the list items a reset their color
  [...lis].forEach(li => li.classList.remove('active'));

  // add a red class to the clicked element
  classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<ul class="colors">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test again</li>
  <li>Tester</li>
  <li>Testify</li>
</ul>
```